# How to switch context in Dragonfly

Tags: python, python-dragonfly

I have tried the Python module for handling speech recognition Dragonfly and successfully run notepad example with Windows speech recognition. Now I would like to try something more general, but I cannot find how contexts are switched, i.e. grammars loaded. There are always lines like:

```
grammar = Grammar("Eclipse", context=DynamicContext(winContext, nixContext))
grammar.add_rule(rules)
grammar.load()
```

But the context is always tied to an executable or window title. How do I switch between grammars at will, like a word command or at least mouse click, key press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a rule which calls a function which does this:

```
grammar.disable()
other_grammar.enable()
```

Have a look at `grammar_base.py` for other relevant functions.

Comment: Answer accepted with reservations, this is working, but I am not sure if explicit enabling and disabling grammars is always viable